# How to find equivalent property in Mozilla of given Webkit CSS property

Tags: css, webkit, mozilla

Are there any tool/website where we can get the equivalent property in Mozilla of given Webkit CSS property?

For example:

```
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(white), to(#869ab3));
euavalent to
    background:-moz-repeating-linear-gradient(white, #869ab3);
```

and many more properties like

1. `-webkit-appearance`
2. `-webkit-border-radius`

or to know that there is not any equivalent property regarding some Webkit CSS, like

```
 -webkit-transition:height 0.5s ease-in, padding-top 0.5s ease-in, padding-bottom 0.5s ease-in;
 -webkit-transition-delay:0.5s;
```

I also want to know the Mozilla equivalent of this property:

```
background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0.2, rgb(51,49,51)),color-stop(1, rgb(156,156,156)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Ultimate CSS generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) To get the cross browser gradient *written for you*.

And you can use [this webpage](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) to see the differences between the vendor specific selectors.

Answer (score 4):

- For most CSS3 properties:
  http://css3generator.com/
- For gradients:
  http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
- Another good CSS3 generator:
  http://css3please.com/
- For `@font-face`:
  http://www.fontsquirrel.com/
- Or, look it up here to see the differences, in the "Browser compatibility" table:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient
- If it isn't in MDC, Google it.